# Strength of 1 1/2" by 1 1/2" Douglas fir

Tags: wood, wood-selection, design

I would like to put a new floor in a tag-a-long trailer. I would like it to be light but strong and I plan on using Douglas fir 1 1/2" by 1 1/2" as my floor joists and to be spaced apart 12" with a 5/8" ply on top.

The trailer is 13' long and it is 7 1/2' wide. the largest span would be 2'. In total the weight would be 2000 lbs. Yes, there is a steel frame and no, the wood I would be putting in will not be exposed like the original.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: The answer depends upon the span and loading, so can you add more information? eg. What is the span length?   What is the maximum load for the trailer? How heavy are the loads you will carry?  What is the length and width of the trailer? How is the floor load transferred to the trailer wheels? (Is there a steel frame at the perimeter?)   You should also consider exposure to the elements so Is the flooring exposed to the exterior?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a photo of the trailer

Comment: thanks the trailer is 13' long and the largest span would be 2' in total the weight would be 2000 lbs.yes there is a steel frame and no the wood i would be putting in will not be exposed like the original was

Comment: it is 7 1/2 ' wide and 13' long it is a scaled down version of a bathroom kitchen and bedroom

Comment: ss1911, it would be best to add the extra information to the Question so that it is plainly visible to anyone popping in with the intention of answering. They may not notice or think to check the Comments for added details.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon your description it appears that the trailer has some sort of metal floor framing at 2' centers In which case the 1 1/2" x 1 1/2" and sheathing members are not carrying a substantial structural load to the frame.  From your description it appears that the trailer is for living space, not cargo so your design loads max out around 50 PSF +/-.  Your sizing appears to be adequate.  If you are replacing an existing floor, evaluate the sizing for the current one.  Was it adequate? For this application pine or fir would be adequate, although I would consider pressure treated lumber since it will be exposed to temperature variations and possible condensation as a result.